# Transparencia DIV avanzada

Tags: html, css, design

Qué tal? quiero lograr dar transparencia a un par de medio círculos a los laterales de un modal como la siguiente imagen, alguien podría decirme si es posible hacerlo?

Lo único que he logrado es crear dos círculos a los costados y hacerlos transparentes, pero como tengo el background del modal, pues no se ve la transparencia que deseo.

[image: Transparencia medio círculos a los costados]

Comment: Hola Nestor. Si, es posible. Pero lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Pon tu comentario como la respuesta a tu solución ya que no necesitas una respuesta @NestorLópez

Answer (score 0):

Logré dar el efecto transparente que deseaba con dos contenedores dando bordes redondeados en las esquinas correspondientes. Encontré una publicación aquí mismo en StackOverflow que me ayudó a solucionar mi problema. Les dejo el enlace por si a alguien le llega a servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012085/invert-rounded-corner-in-css Saludos!